# How do I find the last sent message of specific user discordjs

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to make an bot which automatically sends an embed when a user sends an message, the bot has to delete the old embed.

How would I fetch the last message sent by a specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[User#lastMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=lastMessage) Returns the Message Object of the User's last message.

**Example**:

```js
client.user.lastMessage.delete();
```

**Recommended**:
Check if last message exists first.

```js
if (client.user.lastMessage) {          
   client.user.lastMessage.delete();
}
```

Comment: If my solution helped consider giving it the checkmark